# using spring-boot compile not class found int the jar file

Tags: spring-boot, jar, neo4j, package, classnotfound

When u using spring-boot package your project , u will get a jar file, but in my jar file,there is no program files included.
I'm using

> clean package spring-boot:repackage

It looks like this:
[Program files missed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpd8W.png)
you can get the progject from here:
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

And my develop environment is:
IDE: eclipse-mars
JDK: 1.8
thks!